# ¿Cómo hacer una petición HTTP POST con Ruby?

Tags: api, ruby, http, post

Necesito hacer una petición `POST` a una API de `Google` a la URL:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=ACA_LA_CLAVE&remoteip=IP&response=KEY_RESPONSE
```

Me gustaría hacerlo sin usar una gema especifica para esa API de `GOOGLE` sino de la forma más cercana a lo que traiga `Ruby` 2.2.0 por defecto, de ser posible.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo que esa pregunta necesita decir lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Me salió, haciendo lo siguiente, pero no sé si es una buena práctica:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

recaptcha_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
remoteip = request.remote_ip
uri = URI(recaptcha_url)
options = { 
    :secret => ENV["SECRET_KEY_CAPTCHA"], 
    :remoteip => request.env["REMOTE_ADDR"], 
    :response => user_response 
}
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(recaptcha_url), options)
puts("Body: #{response.body}")

#then parse the json response in the above 'response' variable and check whether
#the API returns a success or failure and return true or false depending on it
#logger.info "------status ==> #{response.body}"
hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
hash["success"] == true ? true : false
```

Comment: La última linea es muy poco ruby, `hash["success"] == true ? true : false` es equivalente a `hash["success"]`. Por otro lado, en vez de `puts` en desarrollo en ruby te conviene usar `p`. El resto parece estar muy bien :) .

Comment: Es una buena respuesta. Lo único, ten en cuenta que en POO y sobre todo si vas a hacer llamadas http desde varias clases, te interesa crear una clase HttpService o similar para encapsular esto y ahorrar código en general.

Comment: @matiasmasca estaría bueno que la marques como respuesta aceptada si estás conforme con ella.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque al final termine usando **[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/)**, este es un script utilizado para hacer un post en `Ruby`, recuerda configurar tus credenciales y el tipo de contenido:

```
  full_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=ACA_LA_CLAVE&remoteip=IP&response=KEY_RESPONSE"    
    uri = URI.parse(full_url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    headers = {'Content-Type' => "application/json", 'Accept-Encoding'=> "gzip,deflate",'Accept' => "application/json" }
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, headers)
    request.body = {'credentials' => {'username' => 'jorgesys', 'key' => 'bombonica'}}
    response = http.request(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la nice_http gem que te simplificará el proceso:
https://github.com/MarioRuiz/nice_http

```
require 'nice_htpp'

http = NiceHttp.new('https://www.google.com/')

req = {
  path: '/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
  data: {
    secret: 'ACA_LA_CLAVE',
    remoteip: 'IP',
    response: 'KEY_RESPONSE'
  }
}

resp = http.post req
```